# How to solve a differential equation with boundary conditions, which one of them is a inequality using python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

It is possible to set a boundary condition like psi(z>L)< eps ?

I have a system:

```
dD/dz = ....  
dPsi/dz = ....
```

And boundary conditions:

```
D(0) = 1,6*Pi  
Psi(z>L) < eps
```

I read about `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` and odeint , but all examples have boundary conditions like: `y(0) = y(1) = 0`

Does anyone know how to set such condition?

Comment: It might help if you explained a bit more about the mathematical problem and how that inequality arises.  It might turn out that it would be more appropriate to ask this question over at the mathematics Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer, if you provided a bit more info about the problem.
If I understand correctly, L is the limit of your integration, so the boundary condition is actually

`Psi(L)=eps`

In case you integrate beyond L, you will probably need to have a condition to check on each iteration (new point, etc). Something along the lines:

```
if z>L and Psi(z)>=eps:
    do the action
```

What this action should be would depend on the problem. Hope this helps.